# IE9 Scrolling bug (border line repeated on screen)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, dhtml

I'm doing a DHTML popup where there is a UL with left floated LI's, that show a list of embroidery designs. In ie9 (does not effect <=IE8) when you scroll down in the UL all of these lines start showing up that should not be there. It almost seems like the bottom border of the UL is tearing and staying on screen. To make things even more weird, when you scroll up, the lines disappear...

Here is a screen shot of the problem:
http://www.flyingtigerssurplus.com/bug-sample.jpg

You can replicate the issue in IE9 (win7) by going to:
http://www.flyingtigerssurplus.com/embroidery.php
Then clicking on "view stock embroidery designs" link in the middle of the form. This will pop up the problem area. Scroll away to replicate.

If anyone has any insight on how to rectify this problem, it would be greatly appreciated! Unfortunately IE is the main browser for this sites user base so leaving it the way it is because IE sucks is not the best solution in this case unfortunately :(

Comment: I'm not seeing that effect in my IE9 (v9.0.8112.16421)

Comment: I've been able to replicate this on multiple computers running ie9. Did you scroll up and down in the box? Do you have hardware excel turned off? perhapse thats the cause. I will try disabling it on mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Matt K for helping me realize what the problem might be... The apparently this is a GPU / Driver issue as when I disabled hardware rendering under advanced in internet options, restarted the browser the issue disappeared.

Aiken to the FF hw acceleration, my crappy intel gpu chipset on my laptop causes things to break when hardware acceleration is turned on... I'm going to have to test this at home now, with my tower that has a much better gpu.

Comment: interesting, didn't even know that was an option. I checked my settings and "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering*" is _not_ checked.