# IE text area has weird lines while scroll

Tags: css, internet-explorer, textarea

I get weird styling issue in IE for text area.
When content is huge  scrollbar appears (as expected) but when I scroll there appears horizontal lines everywhere in the content i scrolled.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286030/ie9-scrolling-bug-border-line-repeated-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea wrap="off"></textarea>
```